# Как сделать начальный атрибут класса пустым списком?

Tags: python, ооп

Суть проблемы:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     value = []
...     def method(self, new_value)
...         self.value.append(new_value)
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.value
[]
>>> a.method(1)
>>> b = A()
>>> b.value
[1]
>>> b.method(2)
>>> b.value
[1, 2]
>>> a.value
[1, 2]
```

Это мне каждый раз в `__init__` обнулять `value`? Так:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.value = []
```

Не очень удобно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Следует различать атрибуты объекта (уникальные для каждого экземпляра класса) и атрибуты класса (общие для всех экземпляров).

Определитесь, что вам именно нужно.

```
def __init__(self): 
     self.value = []
```

создает атрибут объекта, поэтому `value = []` писать не нужно. Т. е. это не "обнуление", это создание атрибута для экземпляра класса при инициализации.

Если же вам нужен общий для всех экземпляров класса список, пишите `value = []` - без обнуления в `__init__`.

---

UPD после комментария. Тогда что-то вроде:

```
class My(object):
    initial = [1, 2, 3]
    def __init__(self):
        # копируем в экземпляр объекта
        self.initial = self.__class__.initial

...

# меняем атрибут класса
My.initial = [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Обнулять конечно не очень правильное слово. Я уже определился что мне нужно, я хочу одинаковые __начальные__ атрибуты класса (общие для всех экземпляров), которые в процессе работы с классом могут поменяться, при этом не изменив начальных атрибутов для экземпляров этого класса. Кстати, только list(возможно еще dict и tuple) ведет себя таким образом что изменяется во всех атрибутах класс.

Comment: Это потому что вы выполняете не присваивание list (dict, tuple), что привело бы к созданию атрибута объекта, а вызов метода классового атрибута

Comment: Видимо это верный ответ, вам самому нравится как это выглядит? Вы делаете дефолтные значения атрибутов в инит?

Comment: При чем тут "нравится"? Да, мне "нравится", потому как это работает, как я ожидаю - классовый атрибут копируется в атрибут объекта при его инициализации. Никакой невидимой магии, если знаешь, как это все работает. Вы определитесь, вам шашечки или ехать? Пайтон и так достаточно красивый язык, и такая конструкция, на мой взгляд, его вовсе не портит.

Answer (score 0):

> Это мне каждый раз в init обнулять value? Так:
>
> def init(self): self.value = []

Именно. Грубо говоря `value` - это список, который разделяют все объекты класса `A`. Что бы у каждого объекта класса он был свой, его нужно создать в конструкторе. Правда не уверен (давно не писал на питоне), может быть атрибуту объекта класса нужно дать имя, отличное от атрибута класса, например `self_value`.

> Не очень удобно.

Почему? Вы напишете это один раз, а дальше этот код будет выполняться автоматом при каждом создании объекта класса.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, дело в том что я люблю объявлять дефолтные значения атрибутов не в ините, смотришь на класс и все сразу видно, какие есть атрибуты и какие. А тут нужно в инит смотреть, отделять обозначения переменных от каких то других действий в данном методе. Конечно можно приучится.

Comment: init специально сделан для того, чтобы в нем можно было инициализировать атрибуты объекта класса. Если у вас слишком много атрибутов, то это повод задуматься о пересмотре класса, объединения части атрибутов во внутренний или сторонний класс и т.д.

Comment: @rnd_d Люблю, не люблю... Несерьезно это как-то. Есть соглашения - извольте следовать

Comment: @fogbit да действительно, вы правы, это плохой знак.

@neoascetic , вы могли бы дать ссылку на соглашение, я почитывал pep'ы но не помню такого. А насчет любви, это достаточно серьезная штука, любовь. Без нее кодиться крайне вяло.